# when validate, dropdown box should be colored instead of alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, zend-framework

In below code,consider i leave empty text box and click on submit : the text box border will turn into red but if i do same for dropdown list then it's not happening.
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    types1 as $val1) { ?>
    ">

```
$(document).on('click', '#save_hospital', function () {
var name = $('#name').val();
var type1 = $('#department_name').find("option:selected").val();             
if (name == '' || name == undefined)
  {
    $('#name').css('border', 'medium solid red');                      
  }
if (type1 == '' || type1 == undefined)
  {
    $('#type1').css('border', 'medium solid red');                     
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post html also.

Comment: type1 should never null so you need to check it with 0.

Comment: @RuchishParikh in this state also it show me alert box but i want drowdown box turn into color

Comment: I have attached working example. Problem is need to change $('#type1') in not correct you need to write dropdown id which is $('#department_name')  @AmolDavkhar

Comment: @RuchishParikh sorry for my previous comment its working now .. I put 0 instead of single quote

Comment: @RuchishParikh i can't, don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#save_hospital', function () {

var selectDept =$('#department_name').find("option:selected").val();             
if (selectDept == 0)
  {
      $('#department_name').css('border', 'medium solid red');   

  }else{
    $('#department_name').css('border', 'none');   
  }

});
```

check this example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c7sqzzuv/

Answer (score 0):

One main problem in our code is you need to use dropdown id in jquery.
Use `$('#department_name')` instead of `$('#type1')`.
Also correct way to check with default option value. Try below code.

**Sample Code**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#save_hospital', function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var type1 = $('#department_name').find("option:selected").val();             
    if (name == '' || name == undefined)
      {
        $('#name').css('border', 'medium solid red');                      
      }
    if (type1 == "" || type1 == 0 || type1 == undefined)
      {
        $('#department_name').css('border', 'medium solid red');                     
      }
     else{
      $('#department_name').css('border', 'none');                     
     }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="department_name" id="department_name">
      <option value="0">Select Department</option>
      <option value="1">Deparatment1</option>
      <option value="2">Deparatment2</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" id="save_hospital" value="save">
```

Comment: it gives alert window but i want to turn dropdown box in to another color